# What functional paradigm is this

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am writing some python code and I am implementing a pattern that I have done repeatedly and in numerous languages. I keep thinking this is some sort of functional paradigm, and that this can be implemented functionally (without use of a `for` loop), but I am not seeing it. `Map` takes a series and returns a new series. `Reduce` takes a series and reduces it to a single result. This is neither of those.

The idea of this function below is to repeatedly apply a transformation to a single string. In this case:

1. Replace all uuids
2. then replace all number groups between 5-9 digits
3. There will be more transforms

```py
def to_template(message):
    mappers = [
        ('[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}', '{.uuid}'),
        (' [0-9]{5,9}.', ' {.request_id}.')
    ]
    result = message
    for pattern, replacement in mappers:
        result = re.sub(pattern, replacement, result)

    return result
```

**The questions:**

1. Can this be implemented functionally?
2. Is there a known functional paradigm for this?

Comment: What you are describing _is_ `Map`.  All `Map` means is a `T -> U` translation, and you _are_ changing the shape of the data even if you're keeping the datatype the same.

Comment: When you use the result of each step as an input to the next step, it's `Reduce`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In functional programming terms, this is a *fold*: you are folding (i.e., reducing) a list of replacement operations to a single string, with a string as the starting point.

In Python, you can write this using the `reduce` function in the `functools` module.

```
from functools import reduce


def to_template(message):
    mappers = [ ... ]
    return reduce(lambda r, p: re.sub(*p, r), mappers, message)
```

`reduce` repeatedly calls `re.sub` using an element from `mappers` for the first arguments and the result of the previous call as the second argument. (The first call uses `message` as the "zeroth" return value of `re.sub`.)

---

Recursively, one could implement `reduce` as

```
def reduce(f, itr, init):
    if not itr:
        return init
    else:
        return reduce(f, itr[1:], f(init, itr[0]))
```

Iteratively, it looks much like your function:

```
def reduce(f, itr, init):
    result = init
    for x in itr:
        result = f(result, x)
    return result
```

---

Theoretically, you could also imagine using function composition to fold a list of functions into a single function that gets applied to  your message.

```
from functools import reduce, partial


def to_template(message):
    mappers = [
        partial(re.sub, '[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}', '{.uuid}'),
        partial(re.sub, ' [0-9]{5,9}.', ' {.request_id}.')
    ]

    # Apply f first, so that reduce applies functions
    # in the order they appear in the list.
    def compose(f, g):
        return lambda x: g(f(x))

    def identity(x):
        return x

    f = reduce(compose, mappers, identity)
    return f(message)
```

However, for a large number of mapping operations, you would probably hit the recursion limit with the nested function calls that `reduce` and `compose` would build up.

Comment: AH! Yes! I know fold and reduce are cousins! Thank you! I am still unfamiliar with python so it didn't occur to me that the last element would be the init. The unpack operator here is handy!

Comment: If you are familiar with Haskell, `reduce` is basically `foldl`. `reduce` is a built-in function, but it was "demoted" from the built-in scope to the `functools` module in Python 3.